# Replacing Synchronization with Atomics

Tags: java, performance, concurrency

I have tried to make modification in below specified code by removing synchronized and replacing `Integer` with `AtomicInteger` .

Is it correct and going to ensure that code does not run into synchronization issue?

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.ciena.ems.server.system.dataManager.layer1Connection;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.ciena.core.util.log.Log;
import com.ciena.ems.dataModel.ComponentDefine;
import com.ciena.ems.dataModel.NmsDistinguishedName;
import com.ciena.ems.dataModel.layer1Connection.Layer1ConnectionBase;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * This class will be used to protect atomicity of Connection operations to protect
 * context of one operation from becoming corrupted (changed) by another concurrent operation.
 */
public class Layer1ConnectionSpace {
    private static final String SUBNETWORK_CONN_PREFIX = ComponentDefine.ComponentType.getString(ComponentDefine.ComponentType.SUBNETWORK)
            + NmsDistinguishedName.DEFAULT_NV_DELIMITER + "MLSN_1" + NmsDistinguishedName.DEFAULT_PAIR_DELIMITER
            + ComponentDefine.ComponentType.getString(ComponentDefine.ComponentType.SUBNETWORK_CONNECTION)
            + NmsDistinguishedName.DEFAULT_NV_DELIMITER;

    //private static Integer defaultConnectionSemaphore = new Integer(-1);
    private static AtomicInteger defaultConnectionSemaphore = new AtomicInteger(-1);       

    //static Hashtable<String, Integer> connectionSpace = new Hashtable<String, Integer>(1000);
    static ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> connectionSpace = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>(1000);

    //private static int connectionSemCount = 0;
    private static AtomicInteger connectionSemCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = "Layer1ConnectionSpace";

    public static Integer getSemaphoreForConnection(String connectionName) {

        if (!connectionName.startsWith(SUBNETWORK_CONN_PREFIX)) {
            connectionName = Layer1ConnectionBase.makeNmsDN(connectionName).toString();
        }
       // synchronized (connectionSpace) {
           // Integer retValue = defaultConnectionSemaphore;
             AtomicInteger retValue = defaultConnectionSemaphore;
           // Integer connectionSemaphore;
             AtomicInteger connectionSemaphore;

            try {
                if (connectionName != null) {
                    connectionSemaphore = (AtomicInteger) connectionSpace.get(connectionName);
                    if (connectionSemaphore != null)
                        retValue = connectionSemaphore;
                    else {
                       // synchronized (connectionSpace) {
                            try {
                                connectionSemaphore = (AtomicInteger) connectionSpace.get(connectionName);
                                if (connectionSemaphore != null)
                                    retValue = connectionSemaphore;
                                else {
                                    retValue = connectionSemaphoreCreate();
                                    connectionSpace.put(connectionName, retValue);
                                }
                            } catch (Throwable th) {
                                Log.logError(CLASS_NAME, "Err accessing connectionSpace " + "\nport="
                                        + ((connectionName == null) ? "null" : connectionName));
                            }
                       // }
                    }
                }
                return retValue.get();
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                Log.logError(CLASS_NAME, "Err accessing connectionSpace " + "\nport="
                        + ((connectionName == null) ? "null" : connectionName));
                return retValue.get();
            }
       // }
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    private static AtomicInteger connectionSemaphoreCreate() {
       // connectionSemCount = connectionSemCount - 1;
       // return new Integer(connectionSemCount);
        connectionSemCount.compareAndSet(connectionSemCount.intValue(), connectionSemCount.decrementAndGet());
        return connectionSemCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: removing synchronization often breaks code, what you did broke it. And debugging broken code is off-topic.

Comment: Yes,I have removed synchronization because I'm trying to make it lock free by making use of ConcurrentHashMap and AtomicInteger. It may not be correct which is why I'm seeking  review comments.

Comment: Your code is doing way too much, and can be significantly simplified, but, to know that for sure, you need to add some description about how the `Integer result is used. Does the Integer just need to be unique for each name? Does it even have to be an Integer? Can there be gaps in the integer values returned (like -1, -2, -4, -6)? What if it was just an Object instead of an Integer?. Your question's description tells us nothing about how your code is used, it tells us only what you did to it. If you can update your description, I can likely give you a much better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Too many Atomic Integers?

From a quick reading of your code, it seems that you only need one `AtomicInteger`, which is this one:

```
private static AtomicInteger connectionSemCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

For all of the other `Integer` that you converted to `AtomicInteger`, you never modify their value.  All you do is return them as a regular `Integer`.  So I believe they don't need to be atomic at all.

### Creating a new Integer

As for `connectionSemCount`, the function that creates a new semaphore is awkward.  It could be simplified to:

```
private static Integer connectionSemaphoreCreate() {
    return new Integer(connectionSemCount.decrementAndGet());
}
```

### Naming of variables

I'm not sure what a "connection semaphore" is, and why it is an `Integer` instead of a `Semaphore`.  Normally, a semaphore is a particular type of object used for synchronization.  Here, it looks like it is some kind of counter or ID.  If it is some kind of unique ID, it would be better to name the variable `connectionID` instead of `connectionSemaphore`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not thread safe, does not use atomics the way they were designed to be used, and does not always produce the results you would expect. It appears that the intention of the code is to return an object against which  a connection is locked. That process makes sense, but the way you get that lock object can be simplified a lot.

For a start, get rid of all the exception handling that catches `Throwable`. That's just wrong. If you don't know what exception you are going to catch, then you cannot possibly know how to handle it. Additionally, since none of the code actually throws an exception, it's just noise.

Secondly, you have a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Use it.

You check if connectionName is not null, but it cannot be null, because a few lines up you check whether it starts with the prefix, and that line would throw a NullPointerException if it was null, so the check is (worse than) useless.

You have a number of static fields that are not private, and not final.

The final ***major*** bug is that very time you call the method you get a new Integer value returned.... yes. Even with the same name connection.

Because your map stores an `AtomicInteger`, and because you `return retValue.get();`, the `int` value stored in the `AtomicInteger` `retValue` will be auto-boxed in to a new Integer value.... thus, for example the following code will not work for you (always):

```
Integer semaphoreA = getSemaphoreForConnection("myname");
Integer semaphoreB = getSemaphoreForConnection("myname");

System.out.printf("Equals: %s but Same: %s\n",
       semaphoreA.equals(semaphoreB), semaphoreA == semaphoreB);
```

That will always print Equals "true" for you, but it may not always print Same "true".

Your code could likely be reduced significantly to just:

```
public class Layer1ConnectionSpace {
    private static final String SUBNETWORK_CONN_PREFIX = ComponentDefine.ComponentType.getString(ComponentDefine.ComponentType.SUBNETWORK)
            + NmsDistinguishedName.DEFAULT_NV_DELIMITER + "MLSN_1" + NmsDistinguishedName.DEFAULT_PAIR_DELIMITER
            + ComponentDefine.ComponentType.getString(ComponentDefine.ComponentType.SUBNETWORK_CONNECTION)
            + NmsDistinguishedName.DEFAULT_NV_DELIMITER;


    private static final  ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> connectionSpace = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(1000);

    private static final AtomicInteger connectionSemCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = "Layer1ConnectionSpace";

    private static String qualifiedName(String name) {
        if (name.startsWith(SUBNETWORK_CONN_PREFIX)) {
            return name;
        }
        return Layer1ConnectionBase.makeNmsDN(connectionName).toString();
    }

    public static Integer getSemaphoreForConnection(String name) {

        String connectionName = qualifiedName(name);

        Integer sem = connectionSpace.get(connectionName);
        if (sem != null) {
            return sem;
        }
        sem = new Integer(connectionSemCount.decrementAndGet());
        Integer race = connectionSpace.putIfAbsent(connectionName, sem);
        return race == null ? sem : race;

    }

}
```

Note that, if you are using Java 8, this is possible to simplify even further as:

```
    public static Integer getSemaphoreForConnection(String name) {

        String connectionName = qualifiedName(name);

        return connectionSpace.computeIfAbsent(connectionName,
             k -> new Integer(connectionSemCount.decrementAndGet()));
    }
```